# How to hide element based on id in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic table and one of my columns are two radio buttons. I have to check for the values of those two and if value id greater than 0 I have two hide them both. I have a problem to find the way how to pass ID that I set on the label that holds both radio buttons. Here is my HTML code:

```
<label id="hideRadio_5">
    <input type="radio" name="block" class="blockYes" id="block_1" value="2245"/>
    <span>Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" name="block" class="blockNo" id="block_2" value="2245"/>
    <span>No</span>
</label>

<label id="hideRadio_6">
    <input type="radio" name="block" class="blockYes" id="block_1" value="0"/>
    <span>Yes</span>
    <input type="radio" name="block" class="blockNo" id="block_2" value="0"/>
    <span>No</span>
</label>
```

and here is mu JQuery code:

```
$j( document ).ready(function() {
    /*$j('.blockYes').each(function() {
          if($j(this).val() > 0){
              $j('.hideRadio').hide();
          }
      });*/

      $j('input.blockYes[value="0"]').prop("checked", true);
      $j('input.blockNo[value="-1"]').prop("checked", true);
      $j('input.blockNo[value=""]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

JQuery that I use above works properly and checks radio buttons based on the values but my logic to hide the label does not work. Problem is because I used the class on my labels and in that case all radio buttons were hidden. Then I switched to ID and now I do not how to pass that ID from each label and check the value. If value is greater than 0 I want to HIDE that label. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: just only like this $j('#block_2064').prop("checked", true);

Comment: I think it is not advisable to have two html elements share the same id. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/127180 also says this.

Comment: My ID is not the same always, and I have to use ID on the LABEL not on the radio button.

Comment: You have two `id="block_2065"` elements.

Comment: @user3023588 it doesn't matter if its the same only sometimes. IDs by definition are unique. They must always be unique or things will not operate as you would expect at times. If you need to identify certain elements with the same value use a data-attribute or the class. Just never by ID.

Comment: I understand that i should not have two same ID's but in my case I work with ID that is on the LABEL not on the input field. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

```
$('.blockYes').each(function() {
          if($(this).val() > 0){
              $(this).parent().hide();
          }
});
```

**Fiddle:** [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/nv0bpLbv/)

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot on parent() option in JQuery. Nice and easy.

Comment: @user3023588 : Welcome, if this worked for you please mark it as answer.